# Why was constness removed from Java and C#?

Tags: c#, java, c++, programming-languages, language-features

I know this has been discussed many times, but I am not sure I really understand *why* Java and C# designers chose to omit this feature from these languages. I am not interested in how I can make workarounds (using interfaces, cloning, or any other alternative), but rather in the rationale behind the decision.

*From a language design perspective, why has this feature been declined?*

P.S: I'm using words such as "omitted", which some people may find inadequate, as C# was designed in an additive (rather than subtractive) approach. However, I am using such words because the feature existed in C++ before these languages were designed, so it is omitted in the sense of being removed from a programmer's toolbox.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted, I wonder?!

Comment: likely to trigger subjective/argumentative discussion though the wording of the question in fariness does ask "why the designers chose to" rather than why it was a good/bad thing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In [this](http://www.artima.com/intv/choicesP.html) interview, Anders said:

> Anders Hejlsberg: Yes. With respect to
>   const, it's interesting, because we
>   hear that complaint all the time too:
>   "Why don't you have const?" Implicit
>   in the question is, "Why don't you
>   have const that is enforced by the
>   runtime?" That's really what people
>   are asking, although they don't come
>   out and say it that way.
>
> The reason that const works in C++ is
>   because you can cast it away. If you
>   couldn't cast it away, then your world
>   would suck. If you declare a method
>   that takes a const Bla, you could pass
>   it a non-const Bla. But if it's the
>   other way around you can't. If you
>   declare a method that takes a
>   non-const Bla, you can't pass it a
>   const Bla. So now you're stuck. So you
>   gradually need a const version of
>   everything that isn't const, and you
>   end up with a shadow world. In C++ you
>   get away with it, because as with
>   anything in C++ it is purely optional
>   whether you want this check or not.
>   You can just whack the constness away
>   if you don't like it.

Comment: Which is probably a cop-out, as he knows better. If you correctly declare a foo(Bla&), that's for a reason: it modifies Bla. You don't add a foo(Bla const&) since it can't work. If foo accidentily was declared (Bla&) but it doesn't modify Bla, you can safely add just the const. No overload needed.

Comment: The lack of const-ref is IMHO one of the biggest design weaknesses in .NET.  I'll agree with Mr. Hejlsberg that designing for const-correctness is difficult, but semantic const correctness is often necessary for programs to work correctly, whether or not the framework provides for it, and const-correctness is much easier to achieve if it's designed in from the bottom up than if one has to fudge it later.

Answer (score 7):

I guess primarily because:

- it can't properly be enforced, even in C++ (you can cast it)
- a single const at the bottom can force a whole chain of const in the call tree

Both can be problematic. But especially the first: if it can't be guaranteed, what use is it? Better options might be:

- immutable types (either full immutability, or popsicle immutability)

Comment: if you can't guarantee it in some place, than that place should be encapsulated. alternatively, if the documentation promises not to tweak any input and indeed doesn't, than that's a valid use-case of const_cast, i.e. to interoperate with const-incorrect code. As with hardhats, they provide restrictions as well as protections.

Answer (score 1):

As to why they did it those involved have said so:

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericgu/archive/2004/04/22/118238.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/slippman/archive/2004/01/22/61712.aspx
also mentioned by Raymond Chen
http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/04/27/121049.aspx

In a multi language system this would have been very complex.

Answer (score 1):

As for Java, how would you have such a property behave?  There are already techniques for making objects immutable, which is arguably a better way to achieve this with additional benefits.  In fact you can emulate const behaviour by declaring a superclass/superinterface that implements only the methods that don't change state, and then having a subclass/subinterface that implements the mutating methods.  By upcasting your mutable class to an instance of class with no write methods, other bits of code cannot modify the object without specifically casting it back to the mutable version (which is equivalent to casting away `const`).

Even if you don't want the object to be strictly immutable, if you really wanted (which I wouldn't recommend) you could put some kind of 'lock' mode on it so that it could only be mutated when unlocked.  Have the lock/unlock methods be private, or protected as appropriate, and you get some level of access control there.  Alternatively, if you don't intend for the method taking it as a parameter to modify it at all, pass in a copy of that object, or if copying the entire object is too heavyweight then some other lightweight data object that contains just the necessary information.  You could even use dynamic proxies to create a proxy to your object that turn any calls to mutation methods into no-ops.

Basically there are already a whole bunch of ways to prevent a class being mutated, which let you choose one that fits most appropriately into your situation (hint: choose pure immutability wherever possible as it makes the object trivially threadsafe and easier to reason with in general).  There are no obvious semantics for how `const` could be implemented that would be an improvement on these techniques, it would be another thing to learn that would either lack flexibility, or be so flexible as to be useless.

That is, unless I've missed something, which is entirely possible. :-)

Comment: One could say that "const" turns a mutable object into an immutable with no extra code. With immutable types, you often end up with a second "builder" type. -- Generally I like the declarative expressiveness of "const"; though I agree it's a can of worms.

Answer (score 0):

Java have its own version of const; final. Joshua Bloch describes in his [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)
how you effectively use the final keyword. (btw, const is a reserved keyword in Java, for future discrepancies)

Comment: final is massively different from const, it is but a shadow of it.
readonly in c# is equivalent to final in java except it cannot be applied to local variables (a shame IMO). const is also a reserved word in c# for just the same reason